Determining the approximate age of old duplo bricks
I have a lot of old duplo bricks and want to figure out their approximate age since I'm a bit worried that old duplo bricks might contain unsafe levels of Cadmium after reading reports like this https://tamararubin.com/2019/05/vintage-1970s-legos-test-positive-for-a-high-level-of-a-known-carcinogen-how-can-i-tell-if-my-legos-are-safe/
I have not found any site explaining how to determine the approximate age of duplo bricks, or just if they are older than ~1990? (when Lego supposedly switch to Cadmium free plastic colorants)
Any tips on determining the approximate age? I see some old bricks have the ©LEGO group logo on the back, some says LEGO A/S, some says just ©LEGO and some has no text at all. Also there are several other differences on the back side of the bricks (see images) but I don't know if that can be use for figuring out the age? For reference the yellow brick is a new brick and the other are somewhat old but if they are from the 70s, 80s or 90s I have no idea.




